# X could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to Y

Tags: typescript

X could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to Y

It seems that TS doesn't allow me to do exactly what I want to do. Basically, I have an object/class that has a "call" method that just returns some kind of configuration object for making api calls.

"Request" property is a method that returns the promise itself (an api call), while "payloadHandler" should receive request's response and do whatever with it. Meaning that yeah, payload could be in whatever shape or form, which typescript doesn't like and I can't find a way to infer response type from typed request.

Also, I should mention just in case: I cannot add type parameters to the Entity interface, it's an external class that I'm just augmenting in my actual case.

```
type CallDescriptor<Response> = {
    request: () => Promise<Response>
    payloadHandler(payload: Response): void
};
    
interface Entity {
    call: <Response>() => CallDescriptor<Response>
}
    
const entity: Entity = {
    // 'Response' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'
    call() {
        return {
            request: () => new Promise<number>((res, rej) => res(1)),
            payloadHandler(payload) {
                // payload has to infer type from request's promise's resolve type
                console.log(payload)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The Entity interface dictates that `call` should be a generic method, but your `call` implementation only supports `number` requests. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: `<Response>() => CallDescriptor<Response>` means a function which takes no arguments and returns a `CallDescriptor` for *any* type of `Response` you care to ask for (though due to type erasure the function has no way of knowing at runtime what type of `Response` you did ask for, so this is not really possible). The error message is correct. Perhaps `<Response>` should be a type parameter of the `Entity` interface rather than its `call` method?